# converting a php function a pdo function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to convert this:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);   

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id"));

        return $data;
    }

}
```

to this:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);   
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `admin` WHERE `id` = :user_id");
        $query->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id);
        $query->execute();
        $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r ($data);
    }
}
```

Problem is I cannot get the second bit to work. I keep getting this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /home/ds4887/public_html/silverjet/v1.20/admin/core/functions/main.php
>   on line 39

If you need any other information I will be more than glad to provide it. If not possible than can somebody please so me the correct method to do this. THe top works, the bottom needs to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `$db` variable doesn't exist in that function. Pass it in.

Answer (score 3):

`$db` is not defined within `user_data()`. As such, `$db->prepare()` fails with the error.

You need to establish your [PDO connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) and ensure `user_data()` has access to `$db` either by:

- Passing it as an argument ([Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection))
- Establishing the connection within `user_data()` (inefficient)
- Or using `global` ([poor design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/164998))

Comment: I really want to give you an upvote but you used the "G" word

Comment: @Phil, I almost didn't. Hence it was the last option. I also tagged it as *poor design*. I try to be thorough. Otherwise, it seems the opposite happens - someone down votes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have a problem with variable scoping.  You should pass the `$db` variable to the function (preferred), or use `global $db` declaration to import the variable from the global scope to the function's scope.

Your previous function only worked because you were using `mysql_query()` in a sort of hackish fashion, without specifying the connection for the query.  The default behavior in this case is to use the most recently opened mysql resource link globally, so it just happened to work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing in a value for $db for this line:

```
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `admin` WHERE `id` = :user_id");
```

$db is the connection resource set up when you connected to the database. You need it in PDO, but you can get away without it with `mysql` because `mysql` assumes the last connection you established.